# Doesn't ZK Framework work in Chrome 17?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, zk

I'm looking for UI framework and ZK looks promossing. I look at ZK demos and most of examples doesn't work. Doesn't ZK support Chrome?
I get tons of warnings

`event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.`and errors like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '_trackEvent' of undefined` on almost every click. Warning looks like jQuery related, but error makes nothing work.

Does anyone know what's wrong? It a major issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZK wrap dom event to ZK event , and it port all the event properties to ZK event.

That's for backward compatibility , just like how jQuery does, 
and it will still work even after Chrome remove those properties.

About _trackEvent, that's a method from Google Analytics, 
there might be some issue for GA script loading from google .

And it works in my latest chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This is new... I am using ZK for my new applications in my company and we consider chrome as the browser of our choise. We even install chrome to every new user to be sure that our ZK app will work fast and without problems.